# firebase 'run payments with stripe' extension not creating the cloud functions in index.ts (firestore emulator suite)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

im trying to set up the stripe extension for firebase localy with the emulator suite, i followed the steps here: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments after step 3 an extension folder with the file firestore-stripe-payments.env is created and in the firebase.json file the extension gets listed,
[created/changed files by the extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBimm.png)
but thats all what was created, from my understanding some
[cloud functions regarding stripe should be created by the stripe extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wscO0.png)(inside the index.ts file)

so in step 4: to Test this extension locally with '$ firebase emulators:start' i dont know how/where i can see these functions or test them.

also i dont see any collection regarding stripe in firestore(i already created a product in stripe dashboard), it should look like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clGAZ.png)

ps: no error is thrown while execution all steps (i didnt do the last step for the deployment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the firebase-tools to the latest version with "npm install -g firebase-tools" solved it for me, before i had v10.0.8 and only with v10.0.9 the emulator suite supports the extensions feature. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v10.9.0

Answer (score 0):

When you run `firebase emulators:start`, you should get back a link to the emulator UI. When you look at your installed extension in the emulator UI you should be able to see the functions for the extension under "APIs and resources".

For your question about there being no collection regarding Stripe - have you already created the Firestore database? It's called out as a step you need to complete before installing the extension under the "Additional setup" section.

Comment: i dont see anything regarding installed extensions in the emulator ui, https://imgur.com/a/NHlcAnu, i have setup firestore database and its working with the emulator suite

Comment: Have you when you run firebase emulators:start, there were no issues with starting the Extensions emulator? You should be seeing an extensions tab in the emulator UI: https://imgur.com/a/Eq4s9tT

Comment: i skipped the first step of the instructions xD(npm install -g firebase-tools), cause i already had the firebase-tools installed, unfortunately it was the version 10.0.8 and only from v10.0.9 it has the extension support, so i see the extensions now and everythings seems to be fine for now. do i need to close the thread?